# Smoke render is too thin

Tags: eevee-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I've just started to work on blender and today I've been playing around with smoke physics. I've been following some tutorials on youtube and I've found some simple videos with a few minutes of how to work with smoke.

Right now I've have a project with a simple cube for smoke domain and another for smoke flow.

Here's the image of a render of the smoke that I have (file is in the end)

[image: render on eevee]

[image: render on cycles]

What I pretended was it to be thick, more dense.. I've changed the density fields on the options but no luck. It is blue due to the color of the light (blue sun).

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52493

Any can help?

Thanks a lot.

Edit: Here's an image on how it looks on Cycles (first image is in eevee)

Comment: Wrong file I think. In this one there is a Fluid Sim not Smoke.

Comment: thanks for the warning @cgslav, just updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, was able to find a .blend file on the internet that was working and compared the solution with mine. what I was missing:

- On Volumetrics, change the "End" from 1000m to 100m